# Activiti BPM without activiti-explorer

Tags: activiti, business-process-management

I'm totally new to Activiti and BPM in general. However, I would like to create a web-based workflow application for my company so internal/external users can use it.

I don't want the users to log into Activiti-explorer to access the workflow and do their human tasks. So the application should look as a general web app. Is there anyway to do so? and any live demo?

Comment: I probably have an answer which is a little narrower that yours, olease see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218832/integrate-activiti-modeler-using-maven

Answer (score 5):

you can use activiti api and access services of activiti through ProcessEngine. Every thing which is possible with activiti explorer can be done with java so you can create any kind of project in java using ativiti.
basic set up is [here](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#demo.setup.one.minute.version).

Web project example [link](http://programmingoverflow14.blogspot.in/2016/01/jump-start-with-activiti-bpm-along-with.html).

try to run 10 min demo from [here](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_getting_started_10_minute_tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

Activiti-REST apis are available which offer all the functionalities of explorer.  For the workflow designer, i would suggest you integrate the alfresco activiti-modeler into your web app.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for alfresco activiti app as   browser based application advantage you have is you can do modelling and also use it for end users. There is one more admin app using which u can configure it. You don't need any kind of integration in this case.